# MF227DW printer driver

Tags: printer

I am new to Linux so please ELI5. I have installed the Canon MF227DW Linux drivers off the manufacturer support page. The file I downloaded was this
`linux-UFRII-drv-v340-02-usen.tar.gz`

I unpacked it and now inside `linux-UFRII-drv-v340-02-usen` there are the following folders and files inside. My system is 64 bit.

[image: http://imgur.com/a/tOCAG]

How do I go about installing the drivers? None of these are .PPD format

Answer (score 1):

You can install these drivers via the command line by installing the debian packages you see in the folder.

Issue the following command line in a terminal window (right-click on the *Files* window and select *Open in/Terminal*)

```
sudo dpkg --install *.deb
```

Answer (score 0):

at folder where install.sh was extracted start the terminal and do:

```
chmod a+x install.sh
sudo ./install.sh
```